# Как создать jar файл в мавен проекте

Tags: java, maven, jar

У меня не получается в обычном (application)  maven проекте настроить, чтобы при сборке на выходе получался исполняемый .jar файл.

Пробовал как тут
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

как тут  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

и как тут https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/

во всех случаях я имею папку **target**  , а в ней  две папки  **classes** и **generated-sources** но ни в одной из подпапок файла jar нет.

Самое непонятное, что у этого товарища https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/   можно скачать в конце урока проект целиком, что я и сделал. Но и там тоже не генерируется jar файл.

Вот мой pom файл:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaOpenGl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JavaOpenGl</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaOpenGl</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.testmaven.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. В IDEA откройте терминал (через меню `View`⇒`Tool Windows`⇒`Terminal Alt+F12`).
2. В терминале введите `mvn install` (команда должна вводиться в директории, где лежит ваш `pom.xml`).

В случае успешной сборки, в папке target будет лежать Ваш jar-файл.

Также можно настроить сборку jar файла через Artifacts:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-artifacts.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/artifacts.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаем файл `{ProjectName}\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`
2. Пишем в него строчку `Main-Class: main.company.Main` - имя основного класса вместе с пакетом относительно каталога `{ProjectName}\src\main\java`
3. В файле `{ProjectName}\pom.xml` пишем следующее:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>test</artifactId>
       <name>test</name>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <properties>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       </properties>
       <build>
           <finalName>test</finalName>
           <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.6.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>${java.version}</source>
                       <target>${java.version}</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.0.0</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <goal>jar:inplace</goal>
                       <archive>
                           <manifestFile>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                       </archive>
                       <outputDirectory>artifacts</outputDirectory>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </project>
   ```
4. PROFIT..